# Windows Phone 7 App Slows down in Wi-Fi than 3G or LAN

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, wcf-data-services

I've developed a Windows phone app which consumes some data from WCF Service. My app seems to be very slow in Wi-Fi on comparing it with 3G or LAN. I'm a new bee to both Windows phone app dev and WCF. I've verified a number of variables on WiFi bandwidth and connection. Wi-Fi looks good, but the app still slows down. So not sure where the problem is? Do I need to add any configuration to my service to avoid this? Or do I need to check my device? Can anyone help me to find out the cause?

Comment: Is it actually that the data transfer is slower or is your user interface less responsive? Perhaps some #'s would help, like how long it takes to load the data when on WiFi vs 3G.

Comment: i feel data transfer might be slower in WiFi and also not sure how UI response vary between WiFi and 3G.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. Seems like the 3G data and WiFi do not work smoothly when they're both turned on. Disable 3G data and only enable WiFi and vice versa.

This issue appeared for me after the 7.10.8107.79 update.

This bug have been reported to Microsoft and they are looking into the issue.